# Filter duplicate values and count the occurances using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How to carry out this task in VBA?

Example, the following information is contained in a spreadsheet named fraca1 in Excel, note the letters A and F are the column names in Excel and not part of dataset.

```
A                   F
FRACA 012313        Correction 1
FRACA 012313        Correction 2
FRACA 012313        Investigation 1
FRACA 012313        Investigation 2
FRACA 012317        Investigation 1
FRACA 012317        Investigation 2
FRACA 012317        Investigation 3
FRACA 018593        Correction 1
FRACA 035586        Correction 1
```

I have data contained in several columns. I need to find 3 things.

1. What are the unique FRACA numbers in column A.
2. How many cells in column F contain the word "Correction" corresponding to each unique FRACA number.
3. How many cells in column F contain the word "Investigation" corresponding to each unique FRACA number.

This information must then be put into a new spreadsheet in the same workbook. The resulting spreadsheet would look like this:

```
A               B                 C
FRACA No.       Correction No.    Investigation No.
FRACA 012313    2                 2
FRACA 012317    0                 3
FRACA 018593    1                 0
FRACA 035586    1                 0
```

Comment: I guess it would be easier to accomplish this task with pivot-table. However, if you really need excel-vba, one question would be: in column A are the numbers randomly sorted or they always occur in vertical adjacent cells, like you show in the example? For example, could there be another "FRACA 012313", after "FRACA 035586"?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps, it is for the first part of your question. You must have the Microsoft Scripting Runtime reference activated on VBA.

```
''''''''''''''''''
'1-What are the unique FRACA numbers in column A.
''''''''''''''''''
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'For faster running time
'Create the Scripting Dictionary
Dim d As Object
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim myFirstCol() As Variant
Dim i As Long
'Code Assumes data is in Sheet1 and needs to go to Sheet2 (code names)
arrLength = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Columns("A:A"))
ReDim myFirstCol(1 To arrLength)
'First read your input column
For i = 1 To arrLength
    myFirstCol(i) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
Next i
'create the unique keys
For i = LBound(myFirstCol) To UBound(myFirstCol)
    d(myFirstCol(i)) = mySecondCol(i)
Next i
'Now write your keys to Sheet2
Dim v As Variant
i = 2
For Each v In d.Keys()
    Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) = v
    i = i + 1
Next v
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

For the rest of your problem it should be now easier having the unique values of FRACA solved. If I have some time I will complete the answer with the other 2 parts.